# Moderation on Christmas and New Years Eve?

Tags: discussion

Will moderation continue on Christmas and (in between) New Years Eve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the moderator

- Some have kids
- Some have family events
- Some just want to kick back

In the end there will be someone either from WebApps mods or SE Staff to deal with flags.

Comment: I guess the world will keep on turning if it doesn't.....

Comment: Some moderators don't celebrate Christmas, but would enjoy a day off or two ;) @Jacob

Comment: While I haven't bothered to look back and check, I'd also imagine activity would drop off as well.